# Automatically add Non-Default Private Keys SSH Authentication Agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

For convenience purposes I don't have a "default" private key, usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` or `~/.ssh/identity`. I have multiple keys to manage multiple accounts, one for work and one for personal. I use SSH agent forwarding to get proper authentication. It all works just fine.

The problem I have is after every logoff/reboot, the SSH agent does not automatically add the my keys because, it seems, it only looks for the default named keys, as stated by GitHug at: [Error: Permission denied (public key): Make sure you have a key that is being used](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey#make-sure-you-have-a-key-that-is-being-used).

Is there a way to define what keys the SSH agent should automatically add upon loading or will I have to manually add them each time? Possibly create a script that opens upon logon and adds them.

Comment: Did you find a neat way of solving this?

Comment: Nope. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: I've added a `config` file, as [specified here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168). Haven't restarted yet tho!